# Using pwa-builder from Microsoft: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Request failed

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I would like to use a service worker to cache files and improve user experience by providing offline pages. I used the pwabuilder.com to create the files for the website. Unfortunately, even when using the code without any elements to cache it issues the error "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Request failed"

I double checked the code, I tried the different bug fixes shown on Google Developper and Stackoverflow, but none of these helped me fix the issue.

I have this in the HTML file:

```
if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
      if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
        console.log("[PWA Builder] active service worker found, no need to register");
      } else {
        // Register the service worker
        navigator.serviceWorker
          .register("pwabuilder-sw.js", {
            scope: "./"
          })
          .then(function (reg) {
            console.log("[PWA Builder] Service worker has been registered for scope: " + reg.scope);
          });
      }
}
```

The service worker registers sucessfully.

The pwabuilder-sw.js is this one:

```
//This is the service worker with the Advanced caching



    const CACHE = "pwabuilder-adv-cache";

    const precacheFiles = [

      /* Add an array of files to precache for your app */
        '/cms/stylesheets/bootstrap.css',
        '/cms/stylesheets/ifpayroll.css',
        '/cms/stylesheets/animate.css',
        '/cms/stylesheets/fontawesome-webfont.css',
        '/cms/javascript/main.js',
        '/cms/javascript/aos.js',
        '/cms/images/logo@3x.png',
    ];



    // TODO: replace the following with the correct offline fallback page i.e.: const offlineFallbackPage = "offline.html";

    const offlineFallbackPage = "ToDo-replace-this-name.html";



    const networkFirstPaths = [

      /* Add an array of regex of paths that should go network first */

      // Example: /\/api\/.*/

    ];



    const avoidCachingPaths = [

      /* Add an array of regex of paths that shouldn't be cached */

      // Example: /\/api\/.*/

    ];



    function pathComparer(requestUrl, pathRegEx) {

      return requestUrl.match(new RegExp(pathRegEx));

    }



    function comparePaths(requestUrl, pathsArray) {

      if (requestUrl) {

        for (let index = 0; index < pathsArray.length; index++) {

          const pathRegEx = pathsArray[index];

          if (pathComparer(requestUrl, pathRegEx)) {

            return true;

          }

        }

      }



      return false;

    }



    self.addEventListener("install", function (event) {

      console.log("[PWA Builder] Install Event processing");



      console.log("[PWA Builder] Skip waiting on install");

      self.skipWaiting();



      event.waitUntil(

        caches.open(CACHE).then(function (cache) {

          console.log("[PWA Builder] Caching pages during install");



          return cache.addAll(precacheFiles).then(function () {

            if (offlineFallbackPage === "ToDo-replace-this-name.html") {

              return cache.add(new Response("TODO: Update the value of the offlineFallbackPage constant in the serviceworker."));

            }



            return cache.add(offlineFallbackPage);

          });

        })

      );

    });



    // Allow sw to control of current page

    self.addEventListener("activate", function (event) {

      console.log("[PWA Builder] Claiming clients for current page");

      event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());

    });



    // If any fetch fails, it will look for the request in the cache and serve it from there first

    self.addEventListener("fetch", function (event) {

      if (event.request.method !== "GET") return;



      if (comparePaths(event.request.url, networkFirstPaths)) {

        networkFirstFetch(event);

      } else {

        cacheFirstFetch(event);

      }

    });



    function cacheFirstFetch(event) {

      event.respondWith(

        fromCache(event.request).then(

          function (response) {

            // The response was found in the cache so we responde with it and update the entry



            // This is where we call the server to get the newest version of the

            // file to use the next time we show view

            event.waitUntil(

              fetch(event.request).then(function (response) {

                return updateCache(event.request, response);

              })

            );



            return response;

          },

          function () {

            // The response was not found in the cache so we look for it on the server

            return fetch(event.request)

              .then(function (response) {

                // If request was success, add or update it in the cache

                event.waitUntil(updateCache(event.request, response.clone()));



                return response;

              })

              .catch(function (error) {

                // The following validates that the request was for a navigation to a new document

                if (event.request.destination !== "document" || event.request.mode !== "navigate") {

                  return;

                }



                console.log("[PWA Builder] Network request failed and no cache." + error);

                // Use the precached offline page as fallback

                return caches.open(CACHE).then(function (cache) {

                  cache.match(offlineFallbackPage);

                });

              });

          }

        )

      );

    }



    function networkFirstFetch(event) {

      event.respondWith(

        fetch(event.request)

          .then(function (response) {

            // If request was success, add or update it in the cache

            event.waitUntil(updateCache(event.request, response.clone()));

            return response;

          })

          .catch(function (error) {

            console.log("[PWA Builder] Network request Failed. Serving content from cache: " + error);

            return fromCache(event.request);

          })

      );

    }



    function fromCache(request) {

      // Check to see if you have it in the cache

      // Return response

      // If not in the cache, then return error page

      return caches.open(CACHE).then(function (cache) {

        return cache.match(request).then(function (matching) {

          if (!matching || matching.status === 404) {

            return Promise.reject("no-match");

          }



          return matching;

        });

      });

    }



    function updateCache(request, response) {

      if (!comparePaths(request.url, avoidCachingPaths)) {

        return caches.open(CACHE).then(function (cache) {

          return cache.put(request, response);

        });

      }



      return Promise.resolve();

    }
```

It is 100% the same as the one provided on pwabuilder.com except for the cached files that have been added.

```
Manifest: unknown 'orientation' value ignored.
pwabuilder-sw.js:83 [PWA Builder] Install Event processing
pwabuilder-sw.js:87 [PWA Builder] Skip waiting on install
pwabuilder-sw.js:97 [PWA Builder] Caching pages during install
legal.html:63 [PWA] Service worker has been registered for scope: https://www.ifpayroll.lu/
pwabuilder-sw.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Request failed
```

This is what I get.

Comment: Nobody an idea ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to change this line to reflect your real filename, and make sure that file exists:

```
const offlineFallbackPage = "ToDo-replace-this-name.html";
```

Then you can also delete these lines:

```
       if (offlineFallbackPage === "ToDo-replace-this-name.html") {

          return cache.add(new Response("TODO: Update the value of the offlineFallbackPage constant in the serviceworker."));

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The offline fallback page instruction is badly documented IMO/annoying.

These lines can be removed:

```
       if (offlineFallbackPage === "ToDo-replace-this-name.html") {

          return cache.add(new Response("TODO: Update the value of the offlineFallbackPage constant in the serviceworker."));

        }
```